# Two tables side by side and stop the auto-center

Tags: php, css, html-table

I created two tables and wrote the codes perfectly, but somewhat the right table when got long enough will place itself in the center. How can I fix this?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
#schoolmates_tableMain {
width: 30%;
border: 1px;
min-width: 30%;
position: relative;
opacity: 0.99;
background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0);
float: left;
}


#schoolmates_table { 
width: 59%;
border: 1px;
min-width: 59%;
position: relative;
margin: auto; 
padding-top: 10px;  
background: transparent;
}
```

## UPDATE

I also tried putting `float:right;` on the right table and here's the result:

[image]

The right table "got-out of the background" and as you can see the scrollbars if fully downed I cant even see the "Add Friend" link. How can I make the right table always looks like the first-picture and keeps itself in the right?

## HTML

```
<div id = "green_center">
        <br/><br/>

        <table id = "schoolmates_tableMain" cellspacing = 30>
            <tr id = "transparent">
                <td width = "30%">
                    asdasdas
                    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>


<br/>

<?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $myimg = $row['img'];
    $name = "".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname'];
    $user = $row['username'];
    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    $desc = $row['description'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $me = $_SESSION['username'];
    $id = $row['id'];

    if($email==$myemail) {

    } else {
            echo "<table id = 'schoolmates_table'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo "<table border = '0' width = '100%'>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td width = '1%'>";
                            echo "<div id = 'sm_padding'>";

                                if($myimg=="") {
                                    echo "<img width = '100' height = '100' src = './img/blank_profile.jpg' alt = 'Profile Picture'>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<img width = '100' height = '100' src = './profiles/".$row['img']."' alt = 'Profile Picture'>";
                                }

                            echo "</div>";
                        echo "</td>";

                        echo "<td>";
                            echo "<div id = 'home_greetings'>";
                                echo " ".$name."<br/>";
                            echo "</div>";

                            echo "<div id = 'home_small'>";
                                echo "".$row['course']."&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['year']."&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['university']."<br/>";
                                echo "<small>".$desc."</small><br/>";

                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "<div id = 'sm_small'>";

                                $ss="SELECT * FROM friends WHERE me = '$me' AND them = '$user'";
                                $rr = mysqli_query($con,$ss);
                                $cc = mysqli_num_rows($rr);

                                if($cc==1) {
                                    echo "<a href='#' style = 'text-decoration:none; color:#1f8e1c'>Friends</a>";
                                } else {
                                    $ss2="SELECT * FROM friends WHERE me = '$user' AND them = '$me'";
                                    $rr2 = mysqli_query($con,$ss2);
                                    $cc2 = mysqli_num_rows($rr2);

                                    if($cc2==1) {
                                        echo "<a href='#' style = 'text-decoration:none; color:#1f8e1c'>Friends</a>";
                                    } else {
                                        $s = "SELECT * FROM friend_request WHERE me = '$me' AND them = '$user'";
                                        $r = mysqli_query($con,$s);
                                        $count = mysqli_num_rows($r);

                                        if($count==1) {
                                            echo "<a href = 'cancelrequest_com.php?user=$user&school=$theschool' style = 'text-decoration:none; color:#1f8e1c'>Cancel Friend Request</a> ";
                                        } else {
                                            $s2 = "SELECT * FROM friend_request WHERE me = '$user' AND them = '$me'";
                                            $r2 = mysqli_query($con,$s2);
                                            $count2 = mysqli_num_rows($r2);

                                            if($count2==1) {
                                                echo "<a href = 'accept_com.php?user=$user&school=$theschool&id=$id' style = 'text-decoration:none; color:#1f8e1c' >Accept as Friend</a> ";
                                                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                                echo "<a href = 'notnow_com.php?user=$user&school=$theschool&id=$id' style = 'text-decoration:none; color:#1f8e1c' >Not Now</a> ";
                                            } else {
                                                echo "<a href = 'addfriend_com.php?user=$user&school=$theschool' style = 'text-decoration:none; color:#1f8e1c' >Add to Friends List</a> ";
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                }



                                                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                                echo "<a href = 'addfriend_com.php?user=$user' style = 'text-decoration:none; color:#1f8e1c'>View Profile</a> ";
                        echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";


            echo "<td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";

            }


            }
        ?>

        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
```

Here's my green_center code :

```
#green_center {

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
background-color: #D8F0DA;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;

background-image: url(../img/wallpaper.jpg); 
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;

overflow: auto;

}
```

Comment: Avoid words like **perfectly** if something is broken. uh, `float-right`?

Comment: Once the second table extends past the end of the first table, it will have the entire "row" to itself. Since you specify `margin: auto`, you are effectively asking it to center itself in the available space. Consider floating it right if you need it to stay to the right.

Comment: That looks like a _list_ of comments … so you should not be using tables at all …

Comment: @NicholasHazel Yeah you're right sorry, that was pretty dumb.

Comment: @dlev I tried removing the 'margin: auto;' but somewhat it didn't change anything..

Comment: @CBroe So what can you suggest I'll use then?

Comment: @Emo-Punk I didn't say you should remove that, I meant that it explains why you see centering behavior. You still won't get the behavior you want without some other way of pushing the table to right (like floating it right, or setting a margin, or setting its position to absolute and setting `right` etc.)

Comment: @Emo-Punk: _List_ was set in italics for a reason …

Comment: @CBroe What do you mean? I don't get it sorry -.-

Comment: HTML elements `ul`/`ol` and `li` don’t ring any bells …?

Comment: Oh that! Ofcourse that rings a bell. What I thought you meant was a "comment system". Anyways thanks! Can you post an example out if it please?

Comment: Guys.? Can you please help me>

Comment: add overflow auto to the container

Comment: @nol What do you mean? Can you post an example of it?

Answer (score 0):

add

```
#green_center { overflow:auto}
```

to your css

Comment: which one is the parent